# VFP erase command throwing error 1105

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have a strange situation at a couple of sites where the innocuous line

```
ERASE (lcTablePath) RECYCLE
```

is throwing the error

> Error Number:  1105 - Error writing to file XXXXXXXXXXX

`lcTablePath` does have a value and it's pointing to a file that DOES exist across the network via a UNC path. I'm assuming it's a network issue, possibly with permissions.

But why on earth "1105 - Error **writing** to file"?  I'm not WRITING to it at all.

EDIT:  On further investigation, the issue is actually this

FILE(XXX) says "true", ie the file does exist

ERASE (XXX)

OR

lcTemp = FILETOSTR(XXX)

fail, the FILETOSTR with "file not found".

WTF?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's the RECYCLE clause - trying to write to a recycle location that doesn't exist, because the file was on a network location.

Comment: Hmmmm, that's worth a try, I'll investigate at site and see what happens.

Comment: Didn't help.  It turns out that the FILE(XXX) check before attempting the ERASE was lying (see the edit above for the gory details).   Clearly some odd network stuff going on.